# Setting up Eclipse with a unprecise manual

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-2018-12

I want to configure eclipse to use it with a new risc-v processor. For the configuration there is a manual given. But this manual is very unprecise and I'm not sure I will configure it the right way. I hope someone with experience in eclipse configuration can help me (I did work previously with eclipse, but no custom configuration). I'm using Windows 7, and already downloaded Eclipse, Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0).

Here is the manual: 
https://forum.kendryte.com/topic/35/build-kendryte-using-eclipse

I installed cmake, cmake4eclipse plugin (in eclipse) and downloaded the Toolchain (now available from kendryte) and SDK.

For the setting up steps, what is meant with:
2. "put ninja to your search path"?
4. How to "configure cmake. using generate "Eclipse Ninja""
5. Where to "launch openocd with -m0" in eclipse

I would be very grateful if someone with (eclipse) expericene could help me,
thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, we are not specialized on providing *guides* or other lengthy description about many aspects. In the question post we expect to see a **single question** (or closely related questions), on which we can *answer*. But you have so many questions...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I edited the question, because I figured out a lot of points. But I thought it is easier to have all questions in one, because all are related to setting up eclipse.

Comment: The questions are related to setting up Eclipse, but they are not related with **themselves**. That means that you may ask one of that question, get an answer, and both of them will be unrelated with other questions. E.g. "put ninja to your search path" probably means having directory with `ninja` executable listed in the PATH variable.

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev, thank you for your continuing support! I did download ninja and added it to the PATH varible. Now I'm only struggeling to configure cmake to use eclipse ninja and to launch openocd